# Dell D6000 Dock / Macbook Pro 2017

Tags: laptop, drivers, multiple-monitors, macbook-pro, docking-station

I've bought a [Dell D600 Universal Docking Station](http://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/dell-universal-dock-d6000/apd/452-bcyj/pc-accessories) for my  Macbook Pro 2017 and 2 [DELL U2713H Displays](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/accessories/pc-monitors/52545/dell-u2713h-review).

Unfortunately I've been encountering all the issues listed here: https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/949426-known-issues-with-displaylink-on-macos-10-12-sier

I cannot upgrade to high sierra since this is a company laptop and the company isn't ready yet.

I did install this driver: http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/macos (Tried all the mac drivers).

Any suggestion please?

[image: Macbook Pro]

Answer (score 7):

I have a MacBook Pro 15 inch Touch Bar and a Dell D6000 dock. I was able to find this solution from a colleague at work and it worked well for me and some of my users as well.

You have to allow DisplayLink Software

1. System Preferences
2. Security and Privacy
3. On the bottom of the page there will be a lock. 
   Go ahead and unlock that by putting in your password.
4. Select the DisplayLink software to be allowed.

Your MacBook should now be working with the dock and displaying on any connected monitors.

Comment: I found this while looking to fix the same issue for a Macbook, I found that I needed to install drivers from https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/macos

Comment: This worked for me on macos 10.13 but when 10.14 installed it wiped out the driver. On re-installing, that option is nowhere to be found and it no longer works!

Comment: I am unable to find Display Link Software

Comment: My external monitors are mirroring and I don't have the mirroring button clicked any ideas ?